# Multiple VLAN port group configuration on vMware standard vSwitch not working

Tags: vmware, esxi

I need to move servers to different VLANS(10, 20, 30). I tried to configure Multiple port groups in vMWare standard vSwitch. But only Vms in one port group (VLAN10) are able to access internet, rest are not. Can someone please help me on this.
Is it possible or i need to create different Switches for this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need separate port group for each VLAN, but you can use the same standard switch. Of note, please ensure that the uplinks (from the physical host) for that standard switch have proper connectivity to each of those VLANs.